# How to update test case last verdict in Rally using REST API

Tags: web-services, rest, testing, rally

I am successfully able to update Verdict of my testcase, But while updating Last Verdict using `https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcase/28428199725?key=5d4291cf-XXXX-bb3e-b015f486695f` getting following error:

```
"Warnings": [
        "Ignored JSON element Result.Build during processing of this request.",
        "Ignored JSON element Result.LastRun during processing of this request.",
        "Ignored JSON element Result.LastVerdict during processing of this request."
```

I used below payload:

```
{"Result":{"Build":"12.0.0.260", "LastRun":"2015-04-16T19:56:05.000Z", "LastVerdict":"Fail" }}
```

Can some one help me in updating the last verdict ?.

Answer (score 0):

The LastVerdict rolls up to the TestCase from the most recent TestCaseResult logged. Thus you should create a new TestCaseResult and associate it to your TestCase:

`POST https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcaseresult/create`

Body:

```
{
    "TestCaseResult": {
        "Build": "master-39721",
        "Date": "2015-04-02T21:42:13.000Z",
        "Notes": "Logs indicate pass, however code still doesn't produce expected result.",
        "TestCase": {
            "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcase/28428199725",
        },
        "Verdict": "Inconclusive"
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me in fact same i achieved using following curl command.                                                                                       **curl --header "zsessionid:_v1txcplHMCzUNCO7tTvk71u7URzWMhSQI" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d"{\"TestCaseResult\":{\"Build\":\"12.0.0.2\",\"TestCase\":\"/testcase/8199725\",\"Date\":\"2015-04-14T19:56:05.000Z\",\"Verdict\":\"Inconclusive\"}}" https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/TestCaseResult/create**